# Align pivot/cursor along edge

Tags: transforms, normals, transform-orientation

I would like to move a few verts in the normal direction of an edge.  But the 3d cursor doesn't seem to align with the normal direction.  Instead, it snaps to the edge properly, but does not orient in the the correct direction.

What I've tried:

1. Toggled snap
2. Enabled Edge and Align Rotation To Target
3. Shift + RMB drag along edge.

I've attached an image to clarify.

Thank you for any tips or help.

[image]

Comment: If you want to use the normal orientation of the edge, but on different vertices, select the edge such that your orientation is what you want, then "create orientation".  See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/orientation.html#custom-orientations .  For me, the hotkey for this operation is ctrl alt spacebar.

Comment: This was exactly it.  Thank you!  I just watched a few videos to make sure I understood it.

Comment: @Nathan thank you, that's the answer that helped me. The answer posted below works for some situations, but your answer helped me extend an edge in the direction of the edge and snap it to another edge. I think you should write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure whether i understood your right, but if you want to move an edge in direction of its normal, change to "normal" and then press G Z and move your cursor:

[image]

Comment: This is great to know as well, thank you so much!  I'm very new to Blender, so this is going in my notes.  
So in your example, what if I wanted to move other verts or even an object along that same normal you have selected?  From the answer @Nathan shared, I'd have to create a custom orientation.  That seems to do the trick for what I wanted.